# ¿Cuál es la interpretación literal de implementación completa, parcial y su tipo?

Tags: java

> ### **Resumen de herencia**
>
> En general, distinguimos dos propósitos principales del uso de la
>   herencia: podemos usarla para heredar código (código heredado) y
>   podemos usarla para heredar el tipo (subtipeado). El primero es útil
>   para reutilizar código, el segundo para el polimorfismo y la
>   especialización.
>
> - Cuando heredamos a partir de clases concretas (“extends”) hacemos dos cosas: heredamos la implementación y el tipo.
> - Cuando heredamos a partir de interfaces (“implements”) heredamos un tipo pero no la implementación.
> - Cuando heredamos a partir de clases concretas («extend») hacemos dos cosas: heredamos la implementación y el tipo. Cuando heredamos a
>     partir de interfaces («implement») heredamos un tipo pero no la
>     implementación. **Para los casos en que ambas partes sean útiles
>     podemos heredar a partir de clases abstractas; aquí, heredamos el tipo
>     y una implementación parcial.**
> - **Cuando heredamos una implementación completa, podemos elegir agregar o sobrescribir métodos**. Cuando no se hereda ninguna
>     implementación de un tipo o se hereda parcialmente la implementación
>     de un tipo, la subclase debe proveer la implementación antes de que
>     pueda ser instanciada.
> - Algunos otros lenguajes orientados a objetos también proporcionan mecanismos para heredar código sin heredar el tipo. Java no provee
>     este tipo de construcciones.

Lo que esta en negrita no consigo poner la teoría en práctica, pero, si que he probado las dos primeras frases.

Comment: la pregunta es muy buena.. pero podrias aclarar que entiendes (aunque sea poco, a modo de ejemplo) de lo que esta en negrita. Todo esto da para una clase completa, por eso.

Comment: a vale gracias @gbianchi, de hecho reedite la pregunta para que entendieran mi inquietud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Para los casos en que ambas partes sean útiles podemos heredar a partir de clases abstractas; aquí, heredamos el tipo y una implementación parcial.

lo que pasa es que cuando heredas de clases abstract, heredas los metodos/comportamientos que relacionan a todos en comun y es por ello que se refiere a parcial ya que solo implementa el metodo que aplica a todos por ejemplo imagina que la clase base de Triangulo y circulo es la clase Forma:

`public abstract class Forma {
 ...
 public abstract double getArea();
 ..
}`

ya que el area aplica a todos los miebros de la clase forma

## Cuando heredamos una implementación completa, podemos elegir agregar o sobrescribir métodos.

A lo que se refiere con implementacion completa(antonimo de parcial) quiere decir que cuando le haces el extends a una clase concreta puedes sobrescribir los metodos de la clase a la cual le has hecho extends por ejemplo si tengo la clase boton y la extiendo o le heredo la clase JButton puedo heredar todos los metodos de esta, eso si se sobreescribiran @Override, asi:

```
public class boton extends JButton{
...
public void cualquierCosa(){
...
 }
 @Override //Sera sobrescrito por que viene desde la clase component que hereda de la clase JButton que la heredas tu

 public boolean isVisible() {
     return super.isVisible();
 }
}
```

## Cuando no se hereda ninguna implementación de un tipo o se hereda parcialmente la implementación de un tipo, la subclase debe proveer la implementación antes de que pueda ser instanciada.

Subclases abstractas. Para que una subclase de una clase abstracta se convierta en una subclase concreta, debe proveer las
implementaciones de todos los métodos abstractos heredados. De lo contrario, será propiamente abstracta.

## Algunos otros lenguajes orientados a objetos también proporcionan mecanismos para heredar código sin heredar el tipo. Java no provee este tipo de construcciones.

De esa no tengo conocimiento ya que solo conozco el lenguaje Java

Answer (score 0):

El 3er punto (1ro en negrita) podría ejemplificarse de la siguiente manera:

Supongamos que tenemos 3 clases:

1- Profesor
2- Alumno
3- Administrativo

Las 3 clases pueden heredar de una clase abstracta Persona que posea los atributos y los métodos que la describan como tal y le provean el comportamiento correcto como Personas.

```
Public Abstract Class Persona
{
    int dni;
    string nombre;
    string apellido;
    string legajo;

    public string GetLegajo()
    {
       return dni + "-" + "apellido";
    }
}
```

en ésta clase abstracta Persona (ignoro si está sintacticamente correcta en JAVA ), de la que podrían heredar las otras 3, hay un metodo GetLegajo() que devuelve el dni + apellido, es heredado, y no debería ser sobreescrito por ninguna de las 3 clases, ya que su comportamiento es el mismo para todas.

Creo que ésto explica el primer punto en el que tienes dudas, los demas yo tampoco los entiendo :P

Acabo de leer [ÉSTO](https://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/15995/1/POO-3-Herencia-10-11.pdf) , y creo que le estoy errando a la respuesta, te recomiendo leerlo, está en c++ pero para enjtender los conceptos no importa el lenguaje.